# How to safely terminate Pods under load

Tags: kubernetes, hpa

There's a few scenarios where Pods need to be terminated without reducing a Deployment's total capacity:

- Draining nodes for maintenance
- Draining nodes for binpacking
- Misbehaving Pods / handling memory leaks without triggering OOM Killer

Imagining a situation where we have two Pods taking considerable traffic, if using the default workflow of terminating a Pod and then letting Kubernetes react by re-creating it, we'll have 50% our processing capacity for some arbitrary amount of time.

In high throughput applications this will degrade the service level in one or more of the following ways:

- Request queueing in non-multithreaded non-async applications like Rails increases response time
- Higher context switching, in the case of async multithreaded applications, increases response time
- Timeout error spikes in applications with strict response time SLOs and timeouts
- Cascading slowdowns in services that depend on the high throughput application in question, if we don't enforce strict response time SLOs and timeouts

Ideally what I'd look for is some create-before-destroy pattern. Something like: we ask Kube to terminate a Pod, but before removing it from the Endpoints in any service it's listed, it triggers a scale-up, respects the Readiness Gate, then starts terminating the Pod we asked it to terminate. I haven't found any mention of such a pattern in Kubernetes.

How do folks deal with this scenario? I can imagine the following:

- Lower `targeAverageUtilization` of HPA, so we can tolerate a temporary 50% capacity reduction, but this means we'll pay more than we want
- Optimize Pod time-to-ready so we stay underprovisioned for very few seconds, but this seems very difficult when, for instance, AWS Load Balancers take at least 10 seconds to make a new target go healthy
- Create an involved workflow where instead of `kubectl delete [pod]` we:

  - Increase HPA `minReplicas` to one above current replicas
  - Wait for Pod to go ready
  - Wait a few seconds for it to warm-up
  - Run `kubectl delete [pod]` to kill the desired pod
  - Wait for the new replacement pod to go ready
  - Wait a few seconds for it to warm-up
  - Restore `minReplicas` in the HPA
  - Run the risk of this whole operation happening concurrently with a traffic increase/spike and seeing any of the degradation effects I listed above

None of these seem good tho. The last one, especially, won't cover binpacking as we can't replace how the Cluster Autoscaler drains instances.

Answer (score 0):

Disruption Budget:

- https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/disruptions/
- https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/configure-pdb/

Set `minAvailable` to 90% and that will be it.

Comment: Does %-based PDB trigger a scale-up before termination?

Comment: In case of draining - yes. It's called voluntary disruptions. For misbehaving pods without OOM - not sure how to track this. I'd expect liveness probe to cover this and cause pod restart

Comment: A pod restart with a liveness probe will still trigger termination without scaling up first, no? So the pod will go unhealthy, be removed from the Endpoints list, removed from the load balancer, and we'll be 50% short on capacity until a new pod scales up.

Comment: Correct, I have no answer to that part :) There's lack of sync between liveness probes and PDB https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/66230

Comment: Thanks! I'm testing the PDB right now and with a 90% `minAvailable` I get stuck with `Cannot evict pod as it would violate the pod's disruption budget.`. No scale-up happens to reach a quorum where removing the pod would satisfy 90% `minAvailable`. Do I have to manually scale-up?

Comment: With a manual scale-up as a requirement, I think this only answers the manual drain for maintenance scenario. Cluster Autoscaler-triggered drains for binpacking won't happen.

Comment: Yes, so it's actually doesn't scale-up first, in's only terminates, after verifying the budget. But if your pod grace period is larger than pod's startup period - you'll get the new replica before the current is down.

Comment: For cluster binpacking checkout the https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/descheduler#policy-and-strategies. For unstable pods checkout the https://github.com/ptagr/pod-reaper - one may just recreate pods gradually and constantly

Comment: "But if your pod grace period is larger than pod's startup period" -> even if my grace period is high, as soon as the Pod goes into Terminating state, it's removed from the Endpoints list and won't get new traffic, so we're almost immediately 50% down.

Comment: Yes, this is a capacity drop, but not a downtime - existing connections are kept opened until closed by an app or grace period. There's also `preStop` hook https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/#pod-termination I didn't try, but it might actually keep pod in service.

Comment: the Pod is marked as Terminating concurrently with `preStop` running =[ it's also removed from the Endpoints list just as quickly as without a `preStop` hook.